# Change reference ID of jQuery on(change) function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to use a variable to change the reference Id in the script.

```js
var groupId = "#groupOne input";
var groupValue = 1;
var radioValue;

function changeGroup() {
  groupId = "#groupTwo input";
  groupValue = 2;
}

$(groupId).change(function() {
  $('#x').text("Radio " + radioValue + " says " + groupId);
  $('#y').text(groupValue);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radioGroup">
<div id="groupOne">
<input type="radio" name="1" id="1" value="1">
<label for 1="1">Radio 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="1" id="2" value="2">
<label for 1="2">Radio 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="1" id="3" value="3">
<label for 1="3">Radio 3</label>
</div>
<div id="groupTwo">
<input type="radio" name="2" id="4" value="4">
<label for 1="1">Radio 4</label>
<input type="radio" name="2" id="5" value="5">
<label for 1="5">Radio 5</label>
<input type="radio" name="2" id="6" value="6">
<label for 1="6">Radio 5</label>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<input type="button" onclick="changeGroup();" value="Change Group">
</div>
<div id="x"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
```

I have several groups of radio buttons in a div with id #groupOne.

This works as expected.

If #groupOne is changed to #groupTwo with another function the code still runs using the #groupOne Id.

How can I change the reference Id in the line of code to make this work on another div?

Comment: Please don't reference off-site repositories of code. Instead, use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to create a runnable example here on Stack Overflow. Failing that, at least copy the code here so that we have a [mre].

Comment: Sorry. I did not know about Stack Snippets. I'll post the code here.

Comment: Your best bet is to move away from relying on `id`s in the first place as solutions based on them don't scale well (as you are seeing). Instead, set up a `change` event handler on an element that wraps each set of radio buttons and each set will use the same function.

Comment: The code I posted here does not reflect the code on the actual page. There are seven groups of radio buttons in four unique divs. I do not comprehend your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Scott. I'm not savvy enough to do what you ask. Sorry. I'm a self-taught hack...not a hacker, but I hack away until it works. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Hello Stephen, did you see my invitation to chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256968/room-for-travis-j-and-stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id`s are an easy way to reference elements in your page, but they are the hardest to maintain as more elements get added,  more `id`s get created and the JavaScript code has to be adjusted to accommodate the new `id`s. The better solution is to use other means to reference your elements that are reliable, but don't rely on `id`s to identify elements, such as their position in the HTML, the class(es) that the elements use, etc. Instead of trying to figure out how to pass the right `id` to your function, make the function work with any set of radio buttons, regardless of their `name` or `id`.

In the following example, you can see that all `id`s have been removed and there are 3 groups of radio buttons. Each group has a different amount of radio buttons and with different values.

The very simple script doesn't care about any of that and will work no matter how many groups you have.

```js
// Create a function that fires when any radio button has it's selection changed
// regardless of what group it's in.
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(event) {
  // Find the <p> element within the nearest <div> ancestor to the element
  // that got changed.
  let questionText = $("p",event.target.closest("div"));
  console.log("You selected: " + event.target.value + " within the: " + questionText.text() +  " group");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
   <p>Question 1</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="1" value="1">Radio 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="1" value="2">Radio 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="1" value="3">Radio 3</label>    
  </div>
  <div >
    <p>Question 2</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="2" value="one">Radio 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="2" value="two">Radio 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="2" value="three">Radio 3</label> 
    <label><input type="radio" name="2" value="four">Radio 3</label>     
  </div>
  <div >
    <p>Question 3</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="3" value="red">Radio 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="3" value="green">Radio 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="3" value="blue">Radio 3</label> 
    <label><input type="radio" name="3" value="yellow">Radio 3</label> 
    <label><input type="radio" name="3" value="orange">Radio 3</label>     
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: If only I had your skills I might just come out of retirement...but alas, I like being retired.

That is enough for me to figure out what you are implying. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You have no idea the doors you opened up for me with your 'simple' script. I had no clue that those references existed. 

I have since modified your code to suit my needs with different elements. It works exactly as you have written it with the different elements. This will surely allow me to remove hundreds of lines of redundant code on my page.

I know I'm probably breaking the comment rules, but you need to know how much this has helped, and how much your help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Stephen

Comment: @Stephen Thank you. My pleasure. As an educator, there's no better feedback to get!